# Importing content type into schema.graphql in Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am having  hard time, trying to import a .graphql definition/content type to another .graphql file in Meteor.
I tried packages such as [Meteor-GraphQl](https://github.com/Swydo/meteor-graphql) and the famous [GraphQl-Import](https://github.com/prismagraphql/graphql-import) but none of these seems to work.
In my app, I have an api folder which contains all of my definition:

```
-api
--Animal
---animal.graphql 
--Dog
---dog.graphql
---resolvers.js
---dog.js
---dogForm.js
```

In animal.graphql, i've the following:

```
enum A {
  hunted
  hunter
}
scalar Date

interface Animal {
  _id: String!
  name: String
  group: A!
  createdAt: Date
}
```

In dog.graphql, I have the following:

```
#import Animal "../Animals/Animal.graphql"

type Dog implements Animal{
  _id: String!
  name: String!
  group: A!
  ayes: Int!
  createdAt: Date
}

type Query {
  dog: [Dog]
}

type Mutation {
  createDog(
    name: String!
    group: A!
    ayes: Int!
    createdAt: Date
  ): Dog
}
```

If I import and log the dog schema in dogForm.js:

```
import DogSchema from "../Dog/Dog.graphql";
console.log("Dog Schema: ", DogSchema);
```

I find out that the Animal schema is not imported, and I get the error:

```
Type "Animal" not found in document.
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/v38o07k9my) is a codesandbox example.
So what is the best way to import content type and type definition in a .graphql file?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`meteor add swydo:graphql`

In `dog.graphql`:

```
#import "../Animal/animal.graphql"

type Dog implements Animal {
...
```

Comment: I've done that, but I always got:
Uncaught Error: Type "Animal" not found in document.

Comment: Maybe post a bug to their Github with a small reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by simply importing SDL file and concatenating them when needed. Actually, one could use `type Dog implements Animal{ ... }` without importing Animal `#import Animal "../Animals/Animal.graphql"` if the Animal schema has already been compiled (makeExecutableSchema). So I ended up writing a function using [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob), [path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path) and `fs` that automatically import all my .graphql files and resolvers and make them executable. And when working with multiple SDL, i just `import` them and **concatenate** the string.

```
import AnimalSchema "../Animal/animal.graphql";
import DogSchema from "../Dog/Dog.graphql";
let contatSchema = AnimalSchema + DogSchema;
```